# VueJS + Firebase Using the Firebase Binding

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, vuefire

I am trying to learn Vue with Firebase and I have a followed a few tutorials but I am running into a an error I can't seem to figure out. It is with the firebase binding.

I have a firebase config file:

```
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase'

const app =  initializeApp({
  apiKey: "hidden",
  authDomain: "hidden",
  databaseURL: "hidden",
  projectId: "hidden",
  storageBucket: "hidden",
  messagingSenderId: "hidden",
  appId: "hidden"
})

export const db = app.database();
export const namesRef = db.ref('names');
```

And I am exporting the namesRef which works when I am adding to it, but not when I am trying to loop through it.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" v-model="name">
      <button @click="submitName()">add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Bottles</h1>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="name in names" :key="name.key">
          {{name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {namesRef} from '@/firebase'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
    }
  },
  firebase: {
    names: namesRef
  },
  methods: {
    submitName(){
      namesRef.push({name: this.name})
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Several tutorials I have followed shows that you can use a firebase binding like this...

```
firebase: {
 names: namesRef
},
```

I would think that I should be able to loop through names but I am getting an error "[Vue warn]: Property or method "names" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property."

What am I missing from this working?

Answer (score 0):

`names` is not defined on the vue.  Define it in the data method.  Once that's done, realize that the firebase ref is not array-like; so iteration doesn't make sense. It must be "listened to" with the `on()` method...

```
import {db} from '@/firebase'

data() {
  return {
    names: null,
  }
},
mounted () {
  db.ref('names').on('value', dataSnapshot => {
    this.names = dataSnapshot.val()
  })
},
```

With this, the markup can iterate `v-for="name in names"`

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, does Firebase not have it's own binding? I was defining names in the firebase binding. 
firebase: {
 names: namesRef
}

Looking at this working example they are iterating over the array from users in the way I was trying. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vuejs/vuejs.org/tree/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-firebase-validation?from-embed=&file=/index.html

Comment: I saw that and don't see the need.  My projects just export firebase or the database from the config, then build the refs as needed in code.  Simpler, IMO.  I edited to illustrate.